# libwebsocket Linux Eclipse file format not recognized

Tags: linux, gcc, linker-errors

I installed the libwebsocket library onto my Linux Ubuntu computer. It builds ok and installs.

When I add the library to Eclipse, the build completes (so can find all the required header files). The link fails with:

```
arm-dey-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7ve -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/opt/dey/2.6-r1/ccimx6ulsbc/dey-image-qt-x11/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-dey-linux-gnueabi -L/usr/local/lib -lrt -o "Ele"  ./src/error_functions.o ./src/get_num.o ./src/globals.o ./src/gpio.o ./src/main.o ./src/timers.o ./src/uart.o   -ldigiapix -lwebsockets -ljson-c
/opt/dey/2.6-r1/ccimx6ulsbc/dey-image-qt-x11/sysroots/x86_64-deysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-dey-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-dey-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/real-ld: warning: library search path "/usr/local/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Ele] Error 1
makefile:30: recipe for target 'Ele' failed
```

Any ideas ? ( I am quite new to Linux )

Comment: Are you quite sure that `/usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so` is an **arm** file ? I.e. all files used by a cross compiling must match the target architecture.

Comment: I now believe it is not and that i need to build an arm-linux version of the library .. which i am now struggling with